# Python Virtualbox API

Tags: python, api, virtualbox

I have made a command-line interface for virtualbox such that the virtualbox can be controlled from a remote machine. now I am trying  to implement the commmand-line interface using python virtualbox api. For that I have downloaded the pyvb package (python api documentation shows functions that can be used for implementing this under pyvb package). but when I give `pyvb.startVM(self,"name of vm",type='gui')`, it shows an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startVM'
```

Answer (score 3):

[`startVM`](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/pyvb.vb.VB-class.html#startVM) is in `pyvb.vb.VB` class. Also, it's not `'name of vm'`, as docs explain `startVM` should be called with [`pyvb.vm.vbVM`](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/pyvb.vm.vbVM-class.html) as a first parameter and not a string.